Monotonicity of $f$ and $f^{-1}$
Let $f$ be a strictly monotonic function on an interval $I$. Then, is $f^{-1}$ of the same monotonicity?
I believe that the answer is YES. Here is my attempt:
Since $f$ is monotonic in an interval, then it is invertible. If $f$ is strictly increasing and $f^{-1}$ is strictly decreasing on $I$, then for $x_1, x_2 \in I$ such that $x_1 < x_2$, we have
\begin{align} 
x_1 < x_2 &\overset{f\uparrow}{\implies} f(x_1) < f(x_2) \\[2pt] 
&\overset{f^{-1}\downarrow}{\implies} f^{-1}(f(x_1)) > f^{-1}(f(x_2)) \\[6pt]
&\overset{}{\implies} x_1 > x_2, 
\end{align}
a contradiction.
Similarly for $f$ decreasing and $f^{-1}$ increasing.
EDIT: $f$ is continuous on $I$.

Note that strictly decreasing is not the opposite of strictly increasing. What if $f^{-1}$ is not monotone of any kind? Just take two specific points $x_1<x_2$ and prove that $f^{-1}(x_1)<f^{-1}(x_2)$. To do that, assume by contradiction that $f^{-1}(x_1)\geq f^{-1}(x_2)$...

Note also that there is no reason $f^{-1}$ has to be defined on $I$.

If we have additionally that f is continuous in the interval? Then, it has to be the case, isn't it?

@Jacie The statement is correct anyway, I'm just saying that your proof has some problems. (which can be easily fixed)

This question is essentially a duplicate of Inverse of Strictly Monotone Function. Note that while there the OP assumes that the domain of the function is $\mathbb{R}$ (and not, as here, a perhaps more general interval), the OP there also links to and discusses a proof on Wikipedia of the case where (as here) the domain is assumed to be an interval that might not be all of $\mathbb{R}$.

let  $f$ be  strictly monotonic increasing in an interval $I$ Then $f$ is invertible in $I$, let us denote it's inverse by $f^{-1}$.
$f$ is monotonically strictly increasing implies
$x_1<x_2\implies f(x_1)<f(x_2)$
let $x_1, x_2=f^{-1}(y_1), f^{-1}(y_2)$ respectively.
wlog assume $y_1<y_2$.
Assume $x_1=x_2$
Then:
$y_1=f(x_1)=f(x_2)=y_2$
Which contradicts strictly increasing monotonicity of $f$.
Assume $x_1>x_2$
Then:
$y_1=f(f^{-1}(y_1))=f(x_1)>f(f^{-1}(y_2))=f(x_2)=y_2$.
Then $y_1>y_2$ which contradicts our assumption.
Therefore $x_1<x_2$ and $f^{-1}$ is strictly monotonic increasing in $I$.

This proof is not yet correct. You got your inequalities mixed up, and I am not sure whether this is merely a typo or confusion on your part.
Let us assume that $f$ is strictly monotonicly increasing on an interval $I$. Then $f^{-1}$ is a function on $f(I)$ and is also strictly monotonicly increasing on $f(I)$, where to be clear, $f^{-1}(x)$, for each $x \in f(I)$, is defined to be the $u \in I$ such that $f(u)=x$, if there is only one such $u$.

Indeed, first check that $f^{-1}$ as defined is indeed a function on $f(I)$, that for each $x \in f(I)$, there is exactly one $u \in I$ such that $f(u)=x$. Suppose not. Then there are at least two distinct $u,u' \in I$ that satisfy $f(u)=f(u')=x$. But this is impossible as $f$ is strictly monotonic. [Indeed, if $u$ and $u'$ are distinct then $u<u'$ or $u'>u$. If $u<u'$ then $f(u)<f(u')$ so $f(u)$ and $f(u')$ are not equal after all. Likewise if $u'>u$.]

So now having established that $f^{-1}$ is indeed a function on $f(I)$, let $x$ and $y$ be in $f(I)$ with $x < y$. Then let $u=f^{-1}(x)$ and $v=f^{-1}(y)$, with $u,v \in I$. Then it suffices to show that the inequality $u<v$ is true. However, by definition of $f^{-1}$, note that the equations $f(u)= x$ and likewise, $f(v)= y$ hold. And as $f$ is strictly monotonicly increasing on $I$,  the inequality $f(u)<f(v)$ implies the inequality  $u<v$, and so it follows that $u<v$ is indeed true. And so it follows that $f^{-1}$ must be monotonically increasing.


Likewise:
Let us assume that $f$ is strictly monotonicly decreasing on an interval $I$. Then $f^{-1}$ is a function on $f(I)$ and is also strictly monotonicly decreasing on $f(I)$, where to be clear, $f^{-1}(x)$, for each $x \in f(I)$, is defined to be the $u \in I$ such that $f(u)=x$ , if there is only one such $u$.
Can you prove this yourself.

You are correct that the way I had it before was not fully right, I corrected
